# Fast way to quantize numpy vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I have a large number of numpy vectors, each of shape (3,) with 8 bit integer values:

```
vec = np.random.randint(2**8, size=3)
```

I'd like to quantize those vectors to a smaller space by some known reduction factor. I know I can hammer this out in a series of operations by defining another vector with values that define the amount of information loss, dividing `vec` by that vector, then cooercing the resulting values back to integers:

```
>>> vec = np.random.randint(2**8, size=3)
>>> denominator = np.full(3, 8)
>>> divided = vec / denominator
>>> ints = divided.astype(int)
>>> ints *= denominator
>>>
>>> vec
array([205, 182,  99])
>>> ints
array([200, 176,  96])
```

Is there a faster way to quantize these numpy vectors though? I'd be very grateful for any ideas others can share on this question.

Comment: If your quant factor is a power of two you can just clear bits: `vec & 0b11111000`

Comment: Holy moly that's amazing! If you make an answer with a brief discussion of how that works I'll accept it!

Comment: @PaulPanzer If I want to run that operation on all rows of a 2d array, is there a numpy method to do so in a vectorized fashion?

Comment: Just do the same verbatim. `numpy` will broadcast and apply the operation to every element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your reduction factor is a power of two, the operation you are showing amounts to clearing the last few bits. This can be done in one step using the bitwise and operator `&`. You can specify the bitmask directly using Python binary literals `0b11111000` or do `256 - denominator`. So thanks to numpy broadcasting all you need to do is

```
vec & (256 - denominator)
```

Comment: @duhaime It is the default behavior, just put your array in place of vec

Comment: doing this for an int16 resulted in an int32 for me. I was only able to make it work if I explicitly call `np.bitwise_and(vec, 0b1111111100000000, dtype=np.int16)`

Comment: @DanielV That's because your `dtype` is signed, so `0b1111111100000000` is too large to fit. Try `-0b100000000` instead.

Comment: could you elaborate why this work? Does the positive binary literal not have access to the sign bit while the negative does?

Comment: @DanielV With Python ints being arbitrary precision there is no good way of deciding which bit should be the sign bit, so I guess the `0b...` is always interpreted as positive. You can put an explicit `-` in front of it but have no influence on how it is encoded. `numpy` gets to see in the first case the positive number `2**16-2**8` which is too large for `int16`, so it goes for the smallest size that can accomodate both, this number and a sign. In the other case `-2**8` everything fits an `int16`, so no coercion needed.

Comment: I think I get your point but I got confused about your comment "...in the first case the positive number `2**16-2**8`." Where did this come from? Is it an encoding implementation for a binary literal containing `1111111100000000`?

Comment: @DanielV Yep, try `bin(2**16-2**8)`.